# Converting a date to an abbreviated month date

Tags: r, date

From my data set I converted the date into year-month-day, but now I want to format it to an abbreviated version for graphing purposes. So I want to take 2021-03-15 and turn it into March 15 for my graph
I try to do this in my code with

```
NCM_tibble$date <- as.Date(NCM_tibble$date, '%b-%d')
```

but it doesn't change the date. Here is what the dates look like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Provided `NCM_tibble$date` is already of class 'Date', use `format` :

```
NCM_tibble$date <- format(NCM_tibble$date, '%b-%d')
```

If it is not of class 'Date', change it first.

```
NCM_tibble$date <- format(as.Date(NCM_tibble$date), '%b-%d')
```